# Could you please describe how SQL Server 2014 do cardinality estimation of Join predicate?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I found the information about CE of single filter predicate, multiple filter predicated but I have not found anything about JOIN predicate.

Comment: I don't think I understand exactly what you are asking.  Have you looked at the MSDN SQL Server Books Online? See OPERATORS at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174986.aspx and PREDICATES at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189523.aspx